# При уменьшении экрана некорректно отображается блок

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Проблема: при уменьшении экрана .home__description обрезается, вместо того, чтобы сдвигаться (адаптироваться)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для .scroll-down задано: min-width: 150px. А для .home__content: width: 100%; max-width: 1450px;
Данные блоки находятся в flex контейнере.

```
<div class="page">

    <!-- Home -->
    <div class="home">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="home__wrap">
                <div class="scroll-down">
                    <a class="arrow-down" id="arrow-down" href="#">
                        <div class="arrow-down__text">
                            <div class="arrow-down__text-wrap">
                                Вниз
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="arrow-down__icon">
                            <img src="assets/img/home/arrow.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="home__content">
                    <div class="home__container">
                        <div class="home__inner">
                            <div class="home__header">
                                <h2 class="suptitle">(Diagonal Laminated Timber)</h2>
                                <h1 class="title">ЛЕГКИЕ И ПРОЧНЫЕ  ПЛИТЫ ИЗ ДРЕВЕСИНЫ</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="home__description">
                                <p>
                                    Минимальный вес при максимальной прочности / идеальная стабильность
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="home__slider">
                            <div class="home__slick" id="home__slick">
                                <div class="home__slick-item">
                                    <img src="assets/img/home/photo-1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>

                                <div class="home__slick-item">
                                    <img src="assets/img/home/photo-1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>

                                <div class="home__slick-item">
                                    <img src="assets/img/home/photo-1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.home__content -->
            </div><!-- /.home__wrap -->

        </div><!-- .container -->
    </div><!-- /.home -->

</div><!-- /.page -->
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;

    font: 16px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;

    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

p:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;

    list-style: none;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}



/* Page
=========================*/

.page {
    min-width: 320px;

    overflow: hidden;
}



/* Slick slide
r=========================*/

.home__slider {
    height: 406px;
}

.home__slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}


.slick-slide {
    margin-left: 27px;

    position: relative;
}

.slick-list {
    margin-left:-27px;
}

.slick-slider button {
    display: block;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;

    background-color: #e4dfde;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;

    font-size: 0;

    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.slick-slider button:hover,
.slick-slider button:focus {
    background-color: #0085FF;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    z-index: 999;
}

.slick-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.slick-next {
    left: 72px;
}

.slick-prev:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

    border: solid #0085FF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 45%;

    transform: rotate(135deg);

    transition: border-color .2s linear;
}

.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before  {
    border-color: #fff;
}

.slick-next:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

    border: solid #0085FF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 37%;

    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    transition: border-color .2s linear;
}

.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before  {
    border-color: #fff;
}



/* Containers
=========================*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Home
=========================*/

.home {
    background: url("../img/home/bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    position: relative;
}

.home__wrap {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 198px;
}

.home__content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1450px;
    padding-top: 15px;

    border-left: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}

.home__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.home__header {
    width: 665px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.suptitle {
    font: 30px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #5F5F5F;
}

.title {
    font: 900 42px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.home__description {
    width: 435px;

    font: 24px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;

    position: relative;
}

.home__description:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 5px;

    background-color: #0085FF;

    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -49px;
}

.scroll-down {
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 169px;

    position: relative;
}

.arrow-down {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.arrow-down__text {
    max-width: min-content;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;

    font: 14px / 1.1 'Montserrat', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;
}

.arrow-down__text-wrap {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

.arrow-down__icon img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что вы задали элементу `.home__content` ширину больше, чем он может занять в видимой области просмотра (100% ширины контейнера), а мешает ему занять всю ширину элемент `.scroll-down`. Следовательно я указал элементу `.home__content` ширину по формуле `width: calc(100% - 150px);`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;

    font: 16px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;

    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

p:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;

    list-style: none;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}



/* Page
=========================*/

.page {
    min-width: 320px;

    overflow: hidden;
}



/* Slick slide
r=========================*/

.home__slider {
    height: 406px;
}

.home__slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}


.slick-slide {
    margin-left: 27px;

    position: relative;
}

.slick-list {
    margin-left:-27px;
}

.slick-slider button {
    display: block;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;

    background-color: #e4dfde;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;

    font-size: 0;

    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

.slick-slider button:hover,
.slick-slider button:focus {
    background-color: #0085FF;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    z-index: 999;
}

.slick-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.slick-next {
    left: 72px;
}

.slick-prev:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

    border: solid #0085FF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 45%;

    transform: rotate(135deg);

    transition: border-color .2s linear;
}

.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before  {
    border-color: #fff;
}

.slick-next:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

    border: solid #0085FF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    left: 37%;

    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    transition: border-color .2s linear;
}

.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before  {
    border-color: #fff;
}



/* Containers
=========================*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Home
=========================*/

.home {
    background: url("../img/home/bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    position: relative;
}

.home__wrap {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 198px;
}

.home__content {
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    max-width: 1450px;
    padding-top: 15px;

    border-left: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}

.home__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.home__header {
    width: 665px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.suptitle {
    font: 30px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #5F5F5F;
}

.title {
    font: 900 42px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.home__description {
    width: 435px;

    font: 24px / 1.2 'Roboto', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;

    position: relative;
}

.home__description:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 43px;
    height: 5px;

    background-color: #0085FF;

    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -49px;
}

.scroll-down {
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 169px;

    position: relative;
}

.arrow-down {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.arrow-down__text {
    max-width: min-content;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;

    font: 14px / 1.1 'Montserrat', sans-serif;;
    color: #000;
}

.arrow-down__text-wrap {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

.arrow-down__icon img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

    <!-- Home -->
    <div class="home">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="home__wrap">
                <div class="scroll-down">
                    <a class="arrow-down" id="arrow-down" href="#">
                        <div class="arrow-down__text">
                            <div class="arrow-down__text-wrap">
                                Вниз
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="arrow-down__icon">
                            <img src="assets/img/home/arrow.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="home__content">
                    <div class="home__container">
                        <div class="home__inner">
                            <div class="home__header">
                                <h2 class="suptitle">(Diagonal Laminated Timber)</h2>
                                <h1 class="title">ЛЕГКИЕ И ПРОЧНЫЕ  ПЛИТЫ ИЗ ДРЕВЕСИНЫ</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="home__description">
                                <p>
                                    Минимальный вес при максимальной прочности / идеальная стабильность
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="home__slider">
                            <div class="home__slick" id="home__slick">
                                <div class="home__slick-item">
                                    <img src="assets/img/home/photo-1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>

                                <div class="home__slick-item">
                                    <img src="assets/img/home/photo-1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>

                                <div class="home__slick-item">
                                    <img src="assets/img/home/photo-1.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.home__content -->
            </div><!-- /.home__wrap -->

        </div><!-- .container -->
    </div><!-- /.home -->

</div><!-- /.page -->
```

Справка:

[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc())

Comment: Большое спасибо. Действительно, я указал width: 100%, но max-width: 1450px. (Я думал, что width будет подстраивается под размер экрана, ведь я указал max-width: 1450px)

Comment: @get_it_skill вы все верно утверждаете, ширина подстраивается под размер экрана, только пытается подстроиться под всю его ширину, что и выталкивает контент